# Multiple definition error in .o file

Tags: c

I have one a.h file where i have declared so many structures. I am intialising these structures in a.c file(I have included the a.h file) and i want to reuse the same a.h file in another b.c file. When i included the header file a.h in b.c i'm getting the error as multiple definition. Please help me what can be done to prevent this problem and to reuse the same .h file in both .c files.

Answer (score 6):

You must never instantiate things in header files, i.e. never define anything, just declare them.

You should put a single definition of each declared thing in *one* of the C files, and have `extern` declarations in the shared header:

In `mydata.h`:

```
struct Foo {
  float baryness;
  float baziness;
};

extern struct Foo TheFoo;
```

In *one* C file:

```
#include "mydata.h"

struct Foo TheFoo;
```

In other headers in the project:

```
#include "mydata.h"

printf("the baziness is %f right now\n", TheFoo.baziness);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `a.h` should only declare structures—not variables.  Or if it does declare variables, they should be declared `extern` to prevent duplicate definitions.  (Then define them once in one of the .c files.)

The error is caused by multiple definitions of the same variable.  Be sure that `a.c` and `b.c` don't both declare the same variable names.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

You need to not include it twice, i.e., wrap the .h file in the equivalent of

```
#ifndef _MY_H_
#define _MY_H_

/* codez go here */

#endif _MY_H_
```

Answer (score 0):

Your header file should be declared like this..

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

struct MyStruct {

     ...
     ...

};

#endif // MYHEADER_H
```

So even if you include this file in any number of .c files, structures in it will be defined only once.